# Avoid separate function for commandLink action

Tags: jsf-2, el

I would like to use a property of a form element instead of using an additional function to just return a certain value.

**Current situation**

XHTML file:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{menuBean.navigationAction(menuItem)}" ... >
```

Managed Bean behind it:

```
public function navigationAction(MenuItem entry) {
    return entry.getForward();
}
```

**Desired situation**

I would like to skip the method call and directly use the property of `menuItem` to set the destination. Like this:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{menuItem.forward}" />
```

This does unfortunately not work, as the method cannot be found. Is it even possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<h:link outcome="#{menuItem.forward}" .../>
```

The `outcome` parameter takes a value expression that must resolve to a string. The `action` attribute of `h:commandLink` needs a method expression.

Comment: This means I can even skip the `<h:form>` part, since it doesn't submit anything? That would be great, I'll try that in a moment.

Comment: Yes, it will render an "a" html anchor element and will issue a GET request. No `<h:form>` needed.

Comment: The key difference is that `<h:link>` already evaluates the outcome during the rendering of the initial request while the `<h:commandLink>` only evaluates the action during form submit request. That it didn't work for `<h:commandLink>` can only mean that it's been placed inside a `<h:dataTable>` and that the bean is in request scope. The "real" solution for `<h:commandLink>` would be placing the bean in the view scope instead of request scope. But a `<h:link>` is much better if it concerns plain page-to-page navigation.